# ASP.NET 4.0 has not been registered on the Web server

Tags: asp.net

`ASP.NET 4.0 has not been registered on the Web server. You must manually configure your Web site for ASP.NET 4.0 if you want your site to run correctly.`

How can I fix this in *Visual Studio 2012* on *Windows 7*.

Comment: The first two sentences seemed to be an error message. Thus, they should be blockquoted. Also, I fixed spelling and grammar.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -2):

I was getting this same error message when opening a solution (the Target Framework of my project was .NET Framework 4.0) on Visual Studio 2012, except I was using Windows 10 with the .NET Framework 4.6 installed on my computer. I've got it fixed after manually downloading and installing the **Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 update KB3002339**.

Here's the article who pointed me to the solution:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6/

And here's the page where I downloaded the VS2012 Update KB3002339:
https://support.microsoft.com/pt-pt/help/3002339/unexpected-dialog-box-appears-when-you-open-projects-in-visual-studio